# Importance of the ratio of the focal length/ aspect ratio, versus aspect ratio in ellipse?

Tags: geometry

We are investigating the self-assembly of prolate ellipsoids, equal short axes, with different aspect ratios, $\rho$, but constant volume. Besides the energy and entropy which are involved in this problem, the geometry of the ellipse is important as well.

To check the geometrical properties, I have plotted the focal length of the ellipse, divided by the aspect ratio, versus aspect ratio. I emphasis that we kept the volume fixed which means by increasing the long axis, we decrease the length of the short axes. 
The plot reaches to its maximum at exactly aspect ratio 2. Please see the plot.

[image]

Is this something universal? and what does this non-monotonic behaviour mean? What are the consequences of this number? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ and $b$ be major and minor axes of the ellipsoid. Then the focal length is $f=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=b\sqrt{\rho^2-1}$, where $\rho=a/b$ is the aspect ratio. The volume is on the other hand $V=(4/3)\pi ab^2$, whence: 
$b=\root3\of{3V/(4\pi\rho)}$. By inserting this into the previous equation one gets
$$
{f\over\rho}=\root3\of{3V\over4\pi}{\sqrt{\rho^2-1}\over\rho^{4/3}},
$$
which is just the function you plotted. Its derivative is
$$
{d(f/\rho)\over\rho}=\root3\of{3V\over4\pi}{4-\rho^2\over3\rho^{7/3}\sqrt{\rho^2-1}},
$$
which confirms the presence of a maximum at $x=2$. The maximum value of $f/\rho$ is then $\root3\of{3V\over64\pi}\sqrt3$.

Comment: Thank you so much for very useful information. Now my question is: whether it is of great importance or not, as this aspect ratio, 2, seems universal. or what are other interesting things about this number? (if any)

Comment: I don't know: it all depends if $f/\rho$ is a meaningful variable in your case or not. A plot of $f$ versus $\rho$, for intance, does not exhibit any maximum.